# SSIS package to select percentage of row count and create record in a table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

As a part of a package, I am trying to do the below:

I run a query against Table AAA to get the value `X` (which is int). I want to query against table BBB to list out top `X` (result value from Table AAA) percent of the records and then create new records to table CCC based on results from the query. 
So, I created a SQL editor and insert the query from Table AAA under SQLStatement. I created a Result set with Result Name as the column name which holds the `X` value. I created 2 variables...one to store the `X` value and another to store the SQl statement as a string and insert the query from Table BBB under Value. Then I created a OLE DB Source with "SQL command from variable" and use the variable storing SQL statement.

```
select top (@Variable) percent * from BBB WHERE isdisabled <> 1 ORDER BY newid()
```

This always gives me an error saying that `TOP clause contains an invalid value`.

Can anyone help me resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be better as Matt commented to use this solution:
You can skip creating the SQL variable.  In the data source for this TOP query you can select SQL Command instead of table.  Then enter `Select TOP ? * From  BBB WHERE isdisabled <> 1 ORDER BY newid()` and use the variable as a parameter.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b55edd69-0a2c-4f61-bbd9-061f15d1f93e/pass-a-variable-pararmeter-to-an-ssis-data-source-query-sql?forum=sqlintegrationservices

If you need to use your original approach -
You would need to add an expression on the Sql variable so that your first variable is resolved.  You can not hard code @Variable into the value of the Sql variable.

Something like : `"Select Top " + @[User::TopVariable] + " * From ..."`

Comment: My 2 cents is to move the Edit using the count variable as a parameter to the top as the primary solution it is definitely more clean and more easy to troubleshot if someone else ever has to own the package.  But the need for the expression is right on the money for the other method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: When I use variable to pass parameter in SQL command as:
Select TOP ? * From  BBB WHERE isdisabled <> 1 ORDER BY newid()
I got this error:
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error".

And when i use SQL variable as 
Select Top "+@[User::Variable]+" * From Table WHERE isdisabled <> 1 ORDER BY newid()
I got this error: 
Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Invalid column name '+@[User::Variable]+'.".

Comment: For the first option try select top 1 * from BBB.  This will let you know if there is really a permission problem or if you did not set up the parameters correctly.  For the second option the statement has to be in an expression so that the variable gets resolved to the int value.  For example if you give the first variable a default value of 1, then when evaluating the sql variable it should read Select Top 1 * from...

Comment: Thanks Joe for helping me out and I really appreciate it!

When I tried passing the variable as "?" in "WHERE" clause, its working fine but never worked in "select TOP ? * ". I am just wondering if there is a separate way to pass variable for TOP query.

And when I tried with SQL variable, its always giving me syntax error. I tried most of the possible ways to correct the syntax.
Select Top "+@[User::Variable]+" * From FilteredSystemUser WHERE isdisabled <> 1 ORDER BY newid()